# Getting umbraco context from Quartz.net

Tags: umbraco, quartz.net

We're still supporting an old umbraco 4.11 application. We have implemented Quartz.net into the application so that we can run some scheduled tasks.

One of the issues I'm experiencing is that from the Quartz job (which is just a class), I can't get access to any of the nodes. For example, even code as simple as:

```
var homePage = new Node(-1);
```

returns empty properties (although it does seem to suggest it has found the node).

I realise 4.11 is a very old version, but is there any way of getting the root node by specifiying the domain name for example? Or any other methods anyone can think off?

Thanks in advance
dotdev

Answer (score 0):

In older versions ofd Umbraco you cannot call any of the APIs without being in the context of the Umbraco site itself.

Probably the easiest way to accomplish your task would be to create a URL on the site that you can call that performs the task (it could either be a physical page, or you could use the BASE functionality that's in older versions of Umbraco), and call that URL from your Quartz job.